# biblatex show urldate as dd.mm.yyyy instead of d.m.yyyy

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to change the dateformat in my bibliography, which is currently d.m.yyyy (eg 6.7.2022) and should be dd.mm.yyyy (06.07.2022).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
\thefield{urlday}\adddot%
\thefield{urlmonth}\adddot%
\thefield{urlyear}\isdot}
```

I tried calling biber with dateabbrev=false and urldate=long, which doesn't work. Is there a way to display urlday and urlmonth with leading 0, if needed?

Edit: Here is a MWEB (I hope it's minimal enough, but I wasn't sure what I could ommit without issues)

```
\documentclass[12pt, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[ngerman, british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % paragraphs not indentated
\usepackage[backend=biber, dateabbrev=false, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none, urldate=long, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xpatch} % correct dots in chapters and sections
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\xpretocmd\chapterformat
  {\def\autodot{.}}% replace \autodot by a fixed dot for chapter headings
  {}{\cfPatchFailed}%
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.}% replace \autodot by a fixed dot for chapter entries
]{chapter}

\MakeOuterQuote{"} % german quotes
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial
\linespread{1.25} % equals 1.5 spacing in word
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  urldate = {2022-07-06},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\AtEveryBibitem{[\printfield{labelnumber}]\addspace} % Numbers in the bib
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} % no indentation in bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  [\thefield{urlday}\adddot%
  \thefield{urlmonth}\adddot%
  \thefield{urlyear}\isdot]
}
\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I guess something with my language is wonky - the reason I am loading ngerman and british is so that I get `et al.` instead of `u.a.` in my bibliography

Comment: The code shown is not the best way of getting dd.mm.yyyy date format. What *is* the best way depends on your language settings. `biblatex` will adapt its output to the document language. Please show us a small example document that show which bibliography style you use and which language settings your document has (`babel`/`polyglossia`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For more information about how to make a small example, that can be used to reproduce the issue, see, e.g., [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @moewe - I have added a more complete example, I hope that's more helpful!

Comment: So what's the idea with the language settings? Your document is in German and you only want to get "et al." instead of "u.a.". That's why you load `british`?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea originally. However I have now removed `british` and changed the "u.a." by using `\DefineBibliographyStrings`. However there were some other things wrong with the code I have posted here, and I was missing some stuff to get the `urldate` to be formated exactly as `DD.MM.YYYY` (in my specific case I need [] around the date too, but that doesn't really change anything). I'll go ahead and add what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake was using `british` in addition to `ngerman` because I wanted my bibliography to say "et. al" instead of "u.a.", so I removed the british option from `babel` and instead used

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}
```

for that.

Then I removed what I initially hoped to be the solution

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
\thefield{urlday}\adddot%
\thefield{urlmonth}\adddot%
\thefield{urlyear}\isdot}
```

and finally I removed `dateabbrev=false` and `urldate=long` from the biblatex options.

Now `urldate` is displayed as "besucht am DD.MM.YYYY".

To remove the "besucht am" I did

`\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{[#1]}`

which now shows `urldate` as [DD.MM.YYYY].